# Determine if machines on network how open sessions for remote into using Powershell for the scan

Tags: powershell, scripting, remote-access

I am trying to use Powershell to handle a minor, yet useful task. We have to send out emails to make sure different servers are available to remote onto. If all of the max session are being used. So I wanted to create a script that will see what users are logged on to the particular machine. If none, we can then just remote on and do some work, but if the max connenctions are used, then we can call our production room, and ask for then to free up a session. Hopefully this question is stated clear enough for my scenario.

Here is the following code that I have been trying to get to work, but it gives me an error stating that "I do not have access"

Here are some examples of code I was trying out:

```
    #$MachineList = Get-Content -Path C:\coding\powershell\networkDiscovery\servers.ini; # One system name per line
#foreach ($Machine in $MachineList){
#    ($Machine + ": " + @(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Machine -Namespace root\cimv2 -Class Win32_ComputerSystem)[0].UserName);
#}

$Computers = @( 
,   "Sandy32" 
,   "HP4400" 
,   "Mx4300"  
)

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $Computers | 
    Where-Object {-Not $_.Username} | 


Get-WmiObject -Class win32_process ` 
    -computer 'Sandy32' 
    -Filter "name='explorer.exe'" | 
    Foreach-Object { 
        $_.GetOwner() 
    }    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance on this matter, :)

Comment: Run the script as a domain admin, if it works you will know it's a permissions issue.

Answer (score -1):

Does the account that you're trying to log on with have access to the root\cimv2 WMI Namespace? By log on I mean run the script with? Every encounter I've ever had of getting an "Access Denied" exception has yielded a problem with my account running the script having access to WMI on the destination. One thing you might try is logging onto one of the servers via an RDP session (the goal of this script), and see if you can run the following code:

Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object PSComputerName, UserName

If that works, then it should remotely, too. If not, you have an access problem. One other thing you can try running remotely, although this SHOULDN'T have any bearing on the remote call to WMI, is setting the impersonation and authentication levels:

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -Impersonation Impersonate -Authentication PacketPrivacy -ComputerName $computers # this can be an array, or list, of computers, and it will run against all of them